# How to restrict OTP attempts in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am working on a python BE application which will send OTP. we are storing the OTP in MongoDB and expiring it using TTL. We also have another requirement to restrict the OTP attempts made to 3 per hour. Is there any builtin function in Python or Mongo that can help instead of writing rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches to this problem statement, and let's look at a few.

**Using Redis:**
Whenever you get an OTP request for a username, store that username as a key and attempt number as the value in your Redis database with an expiring time of 1 hour.
And check the value of the attempt in Redis DB whenever you get the request for OTP generation and take action if the attempt is less than 3 ( and increment the value )
Since Redis stores data in the cache, there won't be any effect on your existing databases and Redis will be fast as these kinds of operations deserve it.

**TTL**
MongoDB supports document with expiry time, you can implement the above one with Mongo as a database having separate collection only for attempts. But I suggest don't do that. ( let's keep the temporary things separate )

**Separate field**
In the same collection, you can add 2 more fields : **attemptCount** and **lastOtpRequestTime** and whenever you get request for OTP generation, check these values to find whether the last request was less than 1 hour or not.
**if Yes**, then check the **attemptCount** and if attemptCount is less than 3, then generate OTP. greater than 3, leave it.
**if No**, then add current time as lastOtpRequestTime and set attemptCount.

This is also not suggestable as you will be dealing with the existing and important collection for the request which cannot be trusted.

Hope this answer helped you!